# Set mask for matplotlib tricontourf

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some numpy array containing data that I would visualize on a 2D grid. Some of the data is unphysical and I would like to mask this data. However, I could not figure out how to set the mask attribute of `tricontour` correctly. I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import numpy as np

with open('some_data.dat', 'r') as infile:
        x, y, z = np.loadtxt(infile, usecols=(0, 1, 2), unpack=True)
isbad = np.less(z, 1.4) | np.greater(z, 2.1)
mp.tricontourf(x, y, z, mask = isbad)
```

But the resulting figure is simply not masked. I tried [masking part of a contourf plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797520/masking-part-of-a-contourf-plot-in-matplotlib), i.e.

```
z2 = np.ma.array(z, mask= isbad)
mp.tricontourf(x, y, z2)
```

which did not work either. I want to use `tricontourf` instrad of `contourf`, because I do not want to grid my data.

```
z[isbad] = np.nan
```

results in a Segmentation fault when calling tricontourf

Here's the figure, the red colours are the ones I would like to mark as unphysical.[image: A coloured contour plot with an overshooting color axis, due to unphysical data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here comes the trick. I need to collect the indices of triangles (which are indices into z!), evaluate whether they are good or not and then accept only the triangles for that at least one corner is valid (reducing the dimension from (ntri, 3) to ntri

```
import matplotlib.tri as tr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

triang = tr.Triangulation(x, y)
mask = np.all(np.where(isbad[triang.triangles], True, False), axis=1)
triang.set_mask(mask)
colplt = plt.tricontourf(triang, z)
plt.colorbar()
```

Inspired by this link: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tripcolor_demo.html

[image: Coloured contour plot with maksed unphysical region]

Comment: Really should use "any" instead of "all", if a node has a NaN, using all will still allow NaN values into the contouring algorithm, and cause Segmentation faults

Comment: I used a `mask = np.sum(isbad[triang.triangles],axis=1)>1` to test if 2 or 3 nodes were suspect, since I wanted to see results where at least 1 node was in range.

Answer (score 0):

wsj's answer didn't work for me since it didn't remove certain masked points (I think when not all of the nodes were bad).

[This solution](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2015/10/12/cython_nogil/) did:

```
z[isbad] = numpy.NaN
z = numpy.ma.masked_invalid(z)
vmin, vmax = z.min(), z.max()
z = z.filled(fill_value=-999)

levels = numpy.linspace(vmin, vmax, n_points)
plt.tricontourf(x, y, z, levels=levels)
```