# Tricontourf plot with a hole in the middle.

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data defined on a regular Cartesian grids. I'd like to show only some of them with a condition based on the radius from the center. This will effectively create a ring-like structure with a hole in the center. As a result, I cannot use `imshow`. `tricontourf` or `tripcolor` are what I found to deal with it. My code looks something like this:

```
R = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
flag = (R<150)*(R>10)
plt.tricontourf(x[flag], y[flag], data[flag], 100)
```

where `x` and `y` are mesh grids where `data` defines. The problem here is that both `tricontourf` and `tripcolor` try to fill the middle of the ring, where I hope can be left blank.

To be more specific, the one in the left is similar to what I want but I can only get the one in the right with this piece of code shown above.

[image: Sample plots]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows how to mask some parts of the plot based on a condition. Using `imshow` is perfectly possible, and that's what the script below is doing.

The idea is to set all the unwanted parts of the plots to `nan`. To make the `nan` values disappear, we can set their alpha to 0, basically making the plot transparent at those points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-150, 150, 300)
y = np.linspace(-150, 150, 300)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
data = np.exp(-(X/80.)**2-(Y/80.)**2)

R = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
flag =np.logical_not( (R<110) * (R>10) )
data[flag] = np.nan

palette = plt.cm.jet
palette.set_bad(alpha = 0.0)

im = plt.imshow(data)

plt.colorbar(im)
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Just to add that also `tricontourf` can do what you're asking about. [This example from the matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_demo.html) shows exactly what you're looking for, while [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964453/set-mask-for-matplotlib-tricontourf) deals with a similar issue in a more comprehensive way.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating fake data points in the inner hole and set them to `np.nan` or `np.inf`. Alternately, you could set them to a high value (in your case, say simply `1`) and then pass limits to the colour scale so that these high regions are not plotted.

Comment: I tried both `np.nan` and `np.inf`. Both of them give me plots where the middle has one color and the rest has the color corresponding to `0`. As of the alternative method, I tried to set `vmax` to limit the color scale. In that case, all bigger values are plotted as having the maximum value.

Comment: If you set `np.nan`, you will have to set the contour levels manually.